# c# LINQ to dataset IN clause contains, group, min

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, contains, linq-to-dataset

I am new to LINQ but am trying to tackle a tough one right off the bat.  I am trying to do LINQ to dataset and emulate the following query...

```
SELECT smID, MIN(entID) FROM table
WHERE exID = :exID
AND smID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, etc)
GROUP BY smID
```

The code I have so far is as follows...

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["myTable"];

var query =
    from g in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where g.Field<string>("exID") == exID
    && smIDs.Contains(g.Field<string>("smID"))
    group g by g.Field<string>("smID") into rowGroup
    select new
    {
        smID = rowGroup.Key,
        minEntID = rowGroup.Min(g => g.Field<int>("entID"))
    };
```

**exID** is a string variable in the method and **smIDs** is a List of strings also created earlier in the method.  I created the following code to try and see my results and it throws an "System.InvalidCastException" error at query.Count...

```
             if (query.Count() > 0)
             {
                 foreach (var item in query)
                 {
                     string s = item.smID;
                     int i = (int)item.minEntID;
                 }
             }
```

I have been unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.

VS points to...

```
minEntID = rowGroup.Min(g => g.Field<int>("entID"))
```

This is the first two lines of the stack trace...

```
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
```

Any pointers would be most appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to write `where` instead of the first `&&`?

Comment: Also, you could just write `…group g by g.Field<string>("smID")…`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry the first && is where

Comment: Is smID a string or int in the data table? In your original query, it looks like an int, but in your LINQ query you're using strings.

Comment: @CollinK - technically it is a string.  It will never be such but the DB stores it as a varchar and we carried that up into the dataset definition.

Comment: @MarceloCantos - thanks for the tip about eliminating the new in grouping.  Not sure where I saw that earlier.  I changed it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the exception and stack trace, the type you're specifying for the endID field in your query doesn't match the DataType for that column in the DataTable. These must match -- you cannot use the Field method to cast the value to a different type.

Comment: You are correct.  I changed 'code' minEntID = rowGroup.Min(g => g.Field<int>("entID")) 
to 'code' minEntID = rowGroup.Min(g => Utilities.ConvertFieldtoInt(g.Field<object>("entID"))) The helper method converts the object to an int.  Thanks for you help.  Being new to it, I was too focused on the LINQ to look outside the box for an error unrelated to it.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com) to come up with this code:

```
from t in db.Table // your C# table / collection here, of course
where t.ExId == stackoverflow.ExId 
    && (new int[] {1, 2, 3 }).Contains(t.SmId)
group t by new { t.SmId } into g
select new {
   SmId = g.Key.SmId,
   minEntID = g.Min(p => p.EntId)
}
```